# How can I serve 2 different folders using express (Client and Admin)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to build an admin panel for my node.js app. My current folder structure looks like this:

```
client (folder)
  images (folder)
  fonts (folder)
  index.html
  index.css
  index.js

app.js (node.js server code)
package.json
```

I want to have another folder in that root, looking like this:

```
admin (folder)
  index.html
  index.css
  index.js
```

Having only 2 lines of express code in my node.js app (see below), I have tried the first 'logical' thing.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin')))

app.get('/admin', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/admin/index.html`))
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/client/index.html`))
```

But it obviously doesn't work, throws some weird error on the index.html line 1 that '<' is an invalid character or something, so it's broken.

Code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')))

app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/client/index.html`))
```

This is really all the code I use with express currently, and to be honest, I don't even understand it very well. All the routing is done on the client-side, tho, and it works perfectly fine for now.

What I am trying to accomplish here is, whatever route user navigates to, he gets redirected to my client app, and front-end router does the rest (IE localhost:8080/, or localhost:8080/ps4/games...). But if I go to localhost:8080/admin, and only in that case, I want to serve an admin panel, from where I can log in and manage my products, menu items, answer chat messages, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace these 4 lines of your code:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')))
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin')))

app.get('/admin', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/admin/index.html`))
app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/client/index.html`))
```

with these:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname +'/client'));
app.use('/admin', express.static(__dirname +'/admin'));
```

The above express's built in functions allow you to host static files with the path you want. You can find more information about hosting static files in express's documentation at http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. I've been doing some trial and error and as far as I've managed to come is

app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'))
app.use('/admin', express.static(__dirname + '/admin'))

And also in the html files set path to /admin/index.js for script and css as well, just like on the client. Problem is, I need to navigate to localhost:8080/client/ to go to the website, which I don't want to, and any other route than localhost:8080/client/ doesn't work, which I also don't want. I will be doing some more trial and error and see what can I do

Comment: you may have to set  <base href="/"> in your client index.html. In this way your express virtual path matches with your index.html path

Comment: Seems like the issue was somewhere in the same-name files. As far as I understood you can serve multiple folders but it will act as a same folder so you run into same-name problem, and the program reads only 1. However I have came with an idea of an local app for admin dashboard that does this so I'll go that route. Thanks anyway